# Value of the First derivative at the roots of a polynomial

Tags: roots

For a polynomial $ f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $,

$$
f(x) = c - \sum_{k=0}^n x^k
$$
where $ c \geq 0 $

I would like to find the value of $ f'(x) $ for all the roots $ f(x) = 0 $, for [Dirac Delta composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Composition_with_a_function).

I haven't been able to get very far. How should I go about doing this?

Comment: Just so we're clear, we have $f(x) = c-(1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots+x^n) = c-\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$?

Comment: Do you also want to calculate what those roots actually are?

Comment: @BrianTung That only holds for $ x \neq 1 $, but I need the whole domain.

Comment: @LucioTanzini Yeah, I need to roots too, but only the real roots

Answer (score 0):

If $f (x)=(x-a)g (x)$ then, $f'(x)=(x-a)g'(x)+g (x) $ and so $f'(a)=g (a) $.